# What does it mean "parallel"?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, terminology, affine-geometry

I am thinking on a strict definition of the notion of parallel affine sets in a linear space and came to the following

> **Definition 1:** An affine set $A$ is *parallel to* an affine set $B$ in a linear space $X$ if for every point $a\in A$, the set $A$ is a subset of the affine hull $\operatorname{aff}(\{a\}\cup B)$.

This notion yields exactly what is expected for parallel lines, and also for the case of a line, parallel to a plane, but not vice versa. So, this notion of parallel affine sets is not symmetric. Of course, we can symmetrize it, which leads to the following definitions:

> **Definition 2:** An affine set $A$ is *parallel to* an affine set $B$ in a linear space $X$ if either for every point $a\in A$, the set $A$ is a subset of the affine hull $\operatorname{aff}(\{a\}\cup B)$ **or** else for every point $b\in B$, the set $B$ is a subset of  $\operatorname{aff}(\{b\}\cup A)$.

> **Definition 3:** An affine set $A$ is *parallel to* an affine set $B$ in a linear space $X$ if either for every point $a\in A$, the set $A$ is a subset of the affine hull $\operatorname{aff}(\{a\}\cup B)$ **and** for every point $b\in B$, the set $B$ is a subset of  $\mathrm{aff}(\{b\}\cup A)$.

But then those are three different notions.

> **Question.** Is there any standard terminology (and notations) for distinguishing between these three notions of being parallel?

For example, non-symmetric *parallel* in the sense of Definition 1 can be called *subparallel* (denoted by $A\,|\!\!\;\big|\,B$ ), the symmetric notion in Definition 2 can be called *parallel* and denoted by the standard LaTeX symbol $A\parallel B$, and the symmetric notion in Definition 3 can be called *superparallel* (and I do not have any symbol for it).

Is this (sub-super)parallel terminology good, or is there something better or already existing?

**Remark.** With the proposed terminology, a line can be subparallel to a plane but a plane cannot be subparallel to a line. On the other hand, a plane can be parallel to a line and a line can be parallel to a plane (which agrees with the intuitive meaning of parallelity). Two superparallel affine sets have the same dimension and are just shifts of each other (in case the shift is defined).

Comment: Why can't you just say that two affine sets $A$ and $B$ are parallel if one of them can be obtained by a parallel translation of a subset of the other one? Then the single term "parallel" would suffice. It seems that the distinction between your two definitions is only about whether $\dim A\le\dim B$ or $\dim A=\dim B$. You may also want to distinguish between "$A$ is parallel to $B$" (asymmetric relation, used when $\dim A\le\dim B$) and "$A$ and $B$ are parallel to each other" (symmetric relation, used when $\dim A=\dim B$).

Comment: @IosifPinelis In fact these three notions of parallel are well-defined in general linear spaces (which do not have shifts). A linear space is a pair $(X,\mathcal L)$ consisting of a set of points $X$ and a family $\mathcal L$ of subsets of $X$, called lines (with some axioms describing the nature of lines, namely that any two distinct points are contained in a single line and every line contains at least two points).

Comment: I see. I thought you meant the [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Definition) of affine spaces. Why do you then have metric geometry as a tag (as even affine spaces obtained from vector spaces do not have to carry a metric)? This tag and your mentioning of lines and planes made me think that you were mainly interested in the affine space over $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis For purposes of synthetic geometry, the notion of parallel lines is used in  the axiom of parallel lines, which is then used to define shifts, so the notion of parallel cannot be defined via shifts, if we want to avoid the circularity of definitions.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Concerning the choice of tags, to my surprise, it does not suggest the tag  "geometry", nor "euclidean-geometry" so I selected some near tags hoping that it will attract specialists.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Oh, but you begin your post with "I am thinking on a strict definition of the notion of parallel affine sets in a linear space", whereas "synthetic geometry" is not mentioned in your post. I guess that is why I had "in a linear space" in mind. Then it appears that what I said in previous comments would work.

Comment: If my English here is fine then one may say A is in a shadow of B or equivalently that B shadows A (one may say more specifically "in a parallel shadow" or "parashadows" respectively).

Comment: @WlodAA What is the definition of a shadow of an affine set in a linear space?

Comment: Taras, one may define "shadow" but in my comment I meant to introduce terms (terminology) for what you already have rather than defining something on my own.

Comment: @WlodAA I have already a notion of a shadow, but in the betweenness geometry: the shadow of a set $A$ from a point $b$ is the set of all points $x$ such that some point of $A$ is between $x$ and $b$. But I need to have a precise definition of parallel in order to introduce an axiom of parallels (in higher-dimensional synthetic geometry). And there are many non-equivalent versions of the Euclides Parallel Postulate. For example, Playfair Axiom turned out to be not equivalent to the Proclus Axiom, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/450472/61536

Comment: (Taras, term "**generalized** linear set" of incidence geometry would help my reading.)

Comment: @WlodAA I also thought about such a generalized terminology, but have found that the terminology of linear spaces has been accepted and widely used in the general context, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_space_(geometry)

Comment: (I'd consider a shadow given by a pencil of parallel lines).

Comment: @WlodAA And this general meaning of a linear space includes the more restricted meaning of a liner space over a field as a partial case. The notion of parallel should be defined so that it would work in both cases: general and special, and correspond to our intuition.

Comment: @WlodAA But if you consider a shadow given by a pencil of parallel lines for defining parallel affine sets, then you obtain a circular definition, parallel via parallel. What is then a definition of parallel lines?

Comment: If I may make a terminological rermark, using the word *subparallel* for a non-symmetric relation but *superparallel* for a symmetric relation, might cause confusion (I, for instance, would probably be confused if I had to use those terms, since I'd intuitively expect "$A$ is subparallel to $B$" to be synonymous with "$B$ is superparallel to $A$").

Comment: @JochenGlueck I have decided to follow the suggestion of Iosif Pinelis and write "A is parallel to B" for "subparallel" and "A and B are parallel" for "parallel", and nothing (or "A and B are parallel to each other" for superparallel. The most important notion os "parallel" anyway, and "subparallel" is a primitive in this context.